# How to group_concat subgroup with limit in sqlite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have this very simple table

```
create table foo (id int);
create table bar (id int, name text);

insert into foo(id) values (1), (2);
insert into bar(id, name) values (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (2, 'e');
```

and I want to concat `bar.name` for each `foo`, but with the number of `bar.name` limited.

For example, to limit with 2, it should return

```
id | names
1  | a,b
2  | c,d
```

Without the limit, I know I can just write it like this

```
select id, group_concat(name) as names from foo natural join bar group by id;
```

And it just gives me

```
id | names
1  | a,b
2  | c,d,e
```

But I have no idea how to limit `name`s that get past to group_concat.

Also how do I order `name`s that get past to `group_concat`?

Comment: share output shample

Comment: What version of your sqlite?

Comment: There is (unfortunately) no way to guarantee an order of values with `group_concat()`. From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat): *The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.*

Answer (score 1):

In the more recent versions of SQLite, you can use window functions:

```
select f.id, group_concat(b.name) as names
from foo join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by b.id order by b.id) as seqnum
      from bar b
     ) b
     on b.id = f.id
where seqnum <= 2
group by f.id;
```

If you want just two values, perhaps `min()` and `max()` does what you want:

```
select f.id, 
       (case when min(b.name) = max(b.name)
             then min(b.name)
             else min(b.name) || ',' || max(b.name)
        end) as names
from foo join
     bar b
     on b.id = f.id
group by f.id;
```

As you have phrased the problem, the `join` is not necessary:

```
select b.id, group_concat(b.name) as names
from (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by b.id order by b.id) as seqnum
      from bar b
     ) b
where seqnum <= 2
group by b.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a subquery, that gets the concatenation from another, limited subquery should work.

```
SELECT f.id,
       (SELECT group_concat(x.name)
               FROM (SELECT b.name
                            FROM bar b
                            WHERE b.id = f.id
                            ORDER BY b.name
                            LIMIT 2) x) names
      FROM foo f;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=97b985a57fb695cd195669f2bbab45ed)